# advice : manage file transfer between multiple remote servers

Tags: windows, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp, file-transfer

Hoping for a bit of expert advise in best practise.

At the moment I have about 5 servers (some dedicated, some EC2's).  I need to transfer files between them.  I have one server running an SFTP server which I use as a 'middle-man' but this means I'm double-handling data (upload to SFTP, then download from other server).

How do others manage this sort of thing?  Should I run an SFTP server on each server?  Or is there a simpler SSH-based method?

Comment: 1. there is no such thing as a separate `sftp` server, there is only a `ssh` server and an sftp subsystem provided by that `ssh` server. So if you already run ssh servers you have `sftp` servers you can use, except if you manually deactivated that feature in the configuration. 2. there is `scp` as an easier scripting alternative to `sftp` (also based on the `ssh` server) and 3. you might want to take a look at `rsync` and its ability to use `ssh` as a transport layer.

Comment: Thanks!  I failed to mention they are all windows based machines.

Comment: Where does that make a difference?

Comment: I don't know if it does or not.  I just failed to mention that so was adding to the information.

Comment: So do I need to start a server or service on each machine?  If so, what is the best option?

Comment: Do not place additional information in a comment. Use the `edit` button below your question instead.

Comment: If you want to transfer files to a system, then you need to start "some" service which allows that. There are many alternatives what services you want to use, but probably using a simple `ssh` server and one of its subsystems (`sftp` or `scp`) is the easiest approach. If you want to automate file transfer, then making a script and using `scp` is easiest. Or use `rsync` from a central system if things get annoying to keep the systems file in sync.

Comment: Oh, and a general advice: if you use ssh servers, then do yourself a favor and keep security high by using a non-standard port (not 22, but maybe 50022 or something) and disabling password based authentications and root (admin) login. You want to use key based authentication instead and a non priviledged user account.

Comment: Thanks very much - that is really helpful.  Would you have a recommendation for an SSH server?  Do you rate FreeSSHd?

Comment: Sorry, as most users here I do not use MS-Windows myself. So I do not really want to give a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an SFTP server as your 'middle-man', use [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). Create pick up/drop locations on Amazon S3 that your servers can push and pull from. It's cheap, extremely reliable and scalable. File transfers can be scripted via command line or done via GUI (just like FTP).